# What causes read locks in Conan?

Tags: conan

Conan locks packages while they are written to (e.g. install) or read (e.g. ???). Which operations cause a reading lock to be created?

---

The actual issue I have is the recurring problem lots of people seem to have, that locks are left behind by, I assume, interrupted conan processes. I would like to better understand what in conan creates locks.

Comment: Search for the errors you get online and in particular in their bugtracking system. Also, search the sources for them an read the according code.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I already did that, but I am trying to debug what in our CI is even crashing to leave behind the locks that create problems. It's one specific package that regularly hangs, but I have no idea what it is that runs *before* the attempted installation that indefinitely hangs. All the cleanup solutions are only temporary solutions. The lock is a write lock anyway, but I am trying to better understand conan to maybe get a clue what's going wrong in our specific case. For example, does adding a repo create locks? Does adding or authenticating users?

Answer (score 2):

Most Conan operations that read or write to the cache have a lock (implemented with fasteners library using system file locks). They should only be left behind if Conan crashes or is killed badly. If that is the case, there are several alternatives:

- `conan remove --locks` should clean the files that implement the locks
- removing the cache folder (like `.conan` in the user home) completely. After all it should be treated as a cache, and packages will be re-installed or re-built
- The Conan cache is generally not designed for concurrency. These locks are very basic and will only help somehow for some specific concurrent operations (but will not support parallel jobs doing completely unrelated tasks, for that purpose it is necessary to use separate caches). There is the possibility with the `cache_no_locks = True` configuration, the locks system is completely disabled (and all operations should be strictly mutually exclusive and not concurrent)